# How do I swap using a single s/// all occurrences of two substrings?

Tags: regex, perl

How do I write a regex to replace `a` with `b` and `b` with `a` so that `a&b` will become `b&a`?

**UPDATE**

It should replace all occurrences of `a` with `b` and each `b` with `a`. The `a&b` is just an example to illustrate what I want. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are 'a' and 'b' always single characters?

Comment: @DavidO ,they can also be string.

Comment: Information like that is significant in describing the problem, as it eliminates the tr/// solution, which otherwise is efficient and clear.  It also eliminates `s/([^&|][&|][^&|])/reverse $1/e;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional generic way is:

```
my $string = "abcdefedcba";

my %subst = ( 'a' => 'b', 'b' => 'a' );
$string =~ s/(@{[ join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %subst ]})/$subst{$1}/g;

print $string;
```

Non-generically:

```
$string =~ s/(a|b)/{a=>'b',b=>'a'}->{$1}/ge;
```

Comment: @ysth,why is it so complicated that it even involves `sort`? Is this the proper way to do this? In PHP I just need `strtr($str,array('elephant' => 'fridge','fridge' => 'elephant'));`.

Comment: sort is needed if you want abcd to become apple but abcde to become orange, to make sure it checks abcde first.  If you never have one string be a prefix of another, you can omit the sort.

Comment: The non-generic solution is just `s/(a|b)/{a=>'b',b=>'a'}->{$1}/eg`

Comment: @ysth ,What does `/e` switch mean here?

Comment: It means to evaluate the right side as code and substitute its resulting value instead of literally substituting {...

Comment: @ysth ,how to make it case insensitive so that both `Elephant` and `elephant` will be replaced with `FRIDGE`?

Comment: Right, you need `->{lc $1}` and to make your keys all lower case

Comment: @ysth,the final step,`echo 'A|B' | perl -pne '/(a|b)/ ${{ qa<a b b a> }}{lc $1} /gie'`,it's still reporting syntax error...

Comment: @new_perl: you left off the s at the begining

Answer (score 4):

You can use capturing groups and positional replacements to do this:

```
pax$ echo 'a&b' | perl -pne 's/([^&]*)&(.*)/\2&\1/'
b&a
```

The `(blah blah)` bits *capture* the "blah blah" and save it in a register for later use in the replacement string. When used with a replacement section like `\1`, the captured text is placed in the result.

So that regex simply captures all non-ampersand characters into register 1, the an ampersand then all the rest of the string into register 2.

In the substitution, it gives you register 2, an ampersand, then register 1.

---

If, as you mention in a comment, you want to do `&` and `|`, you need to capture and use the *operator* as well:

```
pax$ echo 'a&b' | perl -pne 's/([^&|]*)([&|])(.*)/\3\2\1/'
b&a
pax$ echo 'a|b' | perl -pne 's/([^&|]*)([&|])(.*)/\3\2\1/'
b|a
```

You can see that the positional replacements are slightly different now since you're capturing more groups but the concept is still identical.

Comment: I don't understand it,but seems it will only work for `a&b`,not if `a|b`,right?

Comment: @new_perl: If `a|b` is a use case, you should put it in your question. Or, better, try to just describe your general problem :-)

Comment: @Platinum Azure ,I've already descibed the general problem in my question:) It should replace all occurences of `a` with `b` ,and all `b` with `a`. The `a&b` is just an example to illustrate what I want.Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Per your updated instructions:

```
$str =~ tr/ab/ba/;
```

Comment: @inTide,what if `aa` to `bb` ,`bb` to `aa`,say multiple characters?

Comment: @new_perl it'll still work as long as you're dealing only with characters. (i.e. you want all character a->b and b->a no matter where they are) If you're dealing with words instead, (e.g. you only want aaaa -> bbbb and bbbb -> aaaa but not aa->bb and bb->aa) that's an entirely new matter. You'll have to clarify just exactly what inputs you want if you're not only dealing with single character replacements. This code will work to change all aa to bb and bb to aa though.

Comment: @inTide,yes, I only want aaaa -> bbbb and bbbb -> aaaa but not aa->bb and bb->aa

Comment: @new_perl I'm not sure you can one line that then, it'll probably be a multi-line solution, I'll think on it though if no one else answers.

Comment: If there is a condition to match just add your condition on the end of your statement `$str =~ tr/ab/ba/ if ($str =~ /a{4,4}/);` Then your problem is just to come up with the right match expression.

Comment: @cordsen ,I need to convert as a `whole`,but `tr` tranlates character by character,which is wrong.

Comment: @new_perl: how would you describe the difference between the `aaaa -> bbbb` and `aa->bb` case?  (Edit your question, please.)

Comment: @ysth ,let's contrive a new case, replace `elephant` with `fridge`,and `fridge` with `elephant`. So that `elephant and fridge` will become `fridge and elephant`.

Comment: @new_perl: I want to know what you mean by `I only want aaaa -> bbbb and bbbb -> aaaa but not aa->bb and bb->aa`.  What is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: @new_perl: Fine, but what constrains the matches?  Are you matching words, or a specific number of characters?  Or from the beginning of a string up to &, followed by everything up to the end of the string?  Really, the specification is so vague it's hard to give good answers.  If the problem were well defined, there wouldn't be so much meta-conversation trying to nail down the definition.

Comment: What I want to do is `strtr($str,array('elephant' => 'fridge','fridge' => 'elephant'));`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Comment: @new_perl: then I think you misspoke and you do want `aa->bb and bb->aa` if you are asking to switch a and b.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a variation of this answer. [Beginner Regex: Multiple Replaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476290/beginner-regex-multiple-replaces#answer-1476709)

```
$text =~ s/(cat|tomatoes)/ ${{ qw<tomatoes cat cat tomatoes> }}{$1} /ge;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to do 3 `s///`.

```
$_ = 'a&b'
# First, change every 'a' to something that does not appear in your string
s/a/\0/g;
# Then, change 'b' to 'a'
s/b/a/g;
# And now change your special character to b
s/\0/b/g;
```